# Meteor nested views and yields

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Iam setting up a basic structure of my future meteor app, Iam using meteor and angular. Wanted to combine iron router with ui router but it got pretty bad. So now Iam back on vanilla meteor for routing issue and the task is have standard multipage site but one of the pages is a complex panel with its own subpages.

So I have a global layout with >yield and all content is being rendered there, now this dasboard page is also rendered into this yield, but it has to have yield of its own. How to set up router to make it work? How to prepare template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your preferred router for the top level routing, then for the templates you want to insert into the dashboard use [Template.dynamic](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)

> **{{> Template.dynamic template=template [data=data] }}**
>
> - Choose a template to include dynamically, by name.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - **template** String 
>     The name of the template to include.
> - **data** Object
>     Optional. The data context in which to include the template.
>
> Template.dynamic allows you to include a template by name, where the name may be calculated by a helper and may change reactively. The data argument is optional, and if it is omitted, the current data context is used.
>
> For example, if there is a template named "foo", {{> Template.dynamic
>   template="foo"}} is equivalent to {{> foo}}.

[Here is a tutorial.](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/)

Comment: Its working, but doesnt seem like the pure way, more like a workaround. Iam thinking of providing additional property(with view name) into router configuration and somehow there combine it with helper method.

Comment: Why do you not think this is a pure approach?  The community seems to be moving more to simpler routing solutions (i.e. increasing adoption of the simpler flow:router, away from iron:router), pushing this logic down into the template level.  I'm still currently working with iron:router (planning on switching for next new app) but reducing logic in router in line with these design patterns.