# Meteor with Router - Template Events not triggering

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I had a lot of code that was working, but needed a way to be able to switch "pages" with Meteor, the most commonly suggested solution being the use of `iron-router`. Following their [documentation](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router), I put each page into a `Template`, as in the following:

```
<template name="home">
    <input type="date" id="start-date" style="width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;">
    <!-- More Random Code --> 
</template>
```

which is rendering properly, after I used:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  // render the Home template with a custom data context
  this.render('home', {data: {}});
});
```

Before I was using:

```
Template.body.events({

});
```

which I changed to:

```
Template.home.events({

});
```

However, the code loaded into this no longer works. One function being called inside this is:

```
    "blur #start-date": function (event) {
        if( Meteor.user() && !StartDate.find({email:Meteor.user().emails[0].address}).fetch().length){
            var date = event.target.value;
            StartDate.insert({
                date: date,
                createdAt: new Date(), // current time
                user: Meteor.user()._id,
                email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address
            });
        }else{

        }
    }
```

Comment: **How** the code no longer works? Is this callback even called?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when you were using Template.body because it was operating within the body area of the file. In the snippet of the "home" template you provided, there is no body and even though it is recognized as a template, there is nothing to actually render in there. add head, body tags and also an area for things to actually be rendered. See also: [Meteor nested views and yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980608/meteor-nested-views-and-yields?rq=1)